# Grassmann numbers

Tags: integration, fermions, grassmann-numbers

I am reading Zee's *Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell* and am having some questions about Grassmann numbers. Let $x,y$ be Grassmann numbers. I think I have two relations:

$$e^{x+y}=1+x+y\tag{1}$$ and
$$e^{x+y}=e^xe^y=(1+x)(1+y)=1+x+y+xy,\tag{2}$$

Which is wrong and why? In fact, my question originates from the derivation of the formula:

$$\int dx\int dy\,e^{yAx}=\det A\tag{3}$$

where $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N),y=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_N)$ both are $N$ Grassmann numbers and $A$ is an antisymmetric $N$ by $N$ matrix. For, if $(1)$ holds, it seems that
$$\int dx\int dy\,e^{yAx}=\int dx\int dy\exp\left(\sum_{ij}y_iA_{ij}x_j\right)=\int dx\int dy\left(1+\sum_{ij}y_iA_{ij}x_j\right)=0\,,\tag{4}$$
which is, of course, wrong. So, where is the problem?

Comment: Does the first equality in (2) hold when $x$ and $y$ don't commute? Do they commute here?

Comment: They are Grassmann numbers and therefore anticommute.

Comment: @rioiong yeah he's just saying $e^{x+y} \neq e^xe^y$ if x and y don't commute

Comment: Yes, he is right and I have found the problem in the derivation of (4).

Answer (score 6):

The power series is the definition of exponentiation.

$e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ is a property of that power series that can be derived for the special case when $x$ and $y$ commute.

Comment: For the generalized version of $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ see the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Comment: Watch Leonard Susskind's youtube lecture on "Supersymmetry and grand unification", end of lecture 4, where he discovers after a comment from the audience that with Grassmann numbers, $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ doesn't work. His surprised reaction is priceless. But he rightly notes that the reason why he never noticed this is that it's not really important.

Comment: @NadavHar'El Thanks for this! But 
I think this fact about exponentials is important (so you dont end up computing the wrong thing). It is true for non commuting QM operators too. Susskind probably just had a momentary brain-fart. There's no way he had never used this fact about exponentials.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the problem is here. For Grassmann numbers $x,y,a,b,c,d$, we have
$$e^{x+y}=1+x+y$$but$$e^{ab+cd}=1+ab+cd+\frac{1}{2}(2abcd)\neq 1+ab+cd$$ Therefore, $(1)$ is correct but the derivation in $(4)$ is wrong.

Comment: I am struggling with the same question as OP, but I don't understand how you obtained the correct expression for $e^{ab + cd}$. Would you be able to elaborate or point me in a direction to learn more? Thank you :)

Comment: I think I realized the answer just after commenting; it follows just from the power series definition of the exponential function. I was thinking that the term $(ab + cd)^2$ had to vanish on account of the constituents being Grassmann numbers... but I suppose $ab$ and $cd$ aren't, actually, Grassmann numbers?

Comment: No, $ab$ and $cd$ are not Grassmann numbers.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize this (that if a and b are grassman numbers, ab isn't). It turns out that although individual grassman numbers anti-commute, products of an even number of grassman numbers - like ab and cd actually commute as can be seen by moving elements around from $abcd$ to $cdab$ and watching the sign flip an even number of times.